# Why is this Windows API code causing heap corruption?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

This simple program displays a multi-file properties dialog for a single file.

When I compile this code in Visual Studio 2019 with address sanitizer enabled (`/fsanitize=address)`), I get the following exception on the line `MessageBoxW(...)' in some system DLL:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77BCC97F (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000374:  A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77C0A918).

There is no error if compiled without sanitizer or with VS2022.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(nullptr);
    IShellFolder* pDesktop; // namespace root for parsing the path
    HRESULT hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        return 0;
    }

    HWND m_hWnd = {};
    LPCWSTR fileName = L"c:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
    LPWSTR fileNameDup = _wcsdup(fileName);

    LPITEMIDLIST newPIdL;

    IDataObject* pDataObject = {};
    hr = pDesktop->ParseDisplayName(m_hWnd, nullptr, fileNameDup, nullptr, &newPIdL, nullptr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        LPCITEMIDLIST list[] = { newPIdL };
        hr = pDesktop->GetUIObjectOf(m_hWnd, 1, list, IID_IDataObject, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDataObject));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

            hr = SHMultiFileProperties(pDataObject, 0);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Test", L"Test", 0);
            }
            pDataObject->Release();
        }
        CoTaskMemFree(newPIdL);
    }

    pDesktop->Release();
    free(fileNameDup);
    
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong in this code?

What else could be causing this error?

[image: crash screenshot]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. I've tested a full smart pointer and different version (but equivalent in the way it works): https://pastebin.com/raw/AZU0JCDJ and it does the same. Also tested with a message pump instead of MessageBox. It works fine with Visual Studio 2022 (and "Visual Studio 2022 (v143)" toolset). I guess it's a bug either in ASAN that ships with Visual Studio 2019 or in the Visual Studio 2019 toolset. you might want to report to Microsoft.